# Updating a .cls file with MiKTeX

Tags: installing, miktex, document-classes, updating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

I recently installed MiKTeX 2.9 and also installed a .cls-file. I did this by copying the .cls-file to the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\sim\simauth.cls" and ran Refresh FNDB + Update Formats in MiKTeK Options (Admin). This worked perfectly, and my documents compiled just fine.

This .cls turned out to be an old version, and so I found the newest version of the .cls-file (also called simauth.cls). I just copied this .cls-file to the same directory and the old .cls-file was overwritten. Again I ran Refresh FNDB + Update Formats, but when I compile, the documentclass has not been updated. I also tried deleting the .cls, but I were still able to compile perfectly.

The .cls-file in question is [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1097-0258/homepage/simauth.cls), and it is because of the update-date, \def\update{2010/03/10 v3.00}, that I am sure the .cls has not been updated properly.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check in the log-file the path of the cls-file used by your document. (But you shouldn't put local files in the main tree of miktex. Files there can be overwritten by miktex.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Ok, I feel embarassed now. It used the old .cls-file, which was located in the same directory as the .tex-file. Thank you. Where do you propose I put this .cls file then?

Comment: Create a local texmf tree. Something like `C:\whateveryouwant\tex\latex\sim`. Move the cls to the sim folder. And then add `C:\whateveryouwant` as a new local root in miktex-settings.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Works perfectly, thanks alot. I'd be happy to accept it your comment as an answer if you'd make one.